# Linux NX Client won't switch to full screen or resize in a window

Tags: fedora, centos, nomachine

When establishing a remote desktop session from a Fedora multimonitor PC to a remote Centos 6 PC, the NX client will not switch to full screen mode and the remote desktop will not resize when the window is resized. Keyboard shortcuts like CTRL-SHIFT-F don't work either. How do I fix this?

Comment: While in the client, try Ctrl+Alt R... then do it again. This is not a real answer, but might help you go forward.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an answer, but a workaround is to use the fullscreen option in KDE on the NX client window. Press ALT-F3 to display the menu, and then select Advanced -> Fullscreen.

Then, in the remote session run the command

```
xrandr -s 1920x1080
```

to force the client to resize the desktop. It's not quite the same as a full screen remote desktop, but will suffice for most situations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although it is an old post, NX server requires a fake display dongle like a **HDMI to vga converter** attached to the GPU.
Then it can utilize the full GPU power and re-scaling will work instantly.

I tried with a DP to VGA converter first. It was not working. **HDMI to vga converter** worked like magic.